# How to receive and decode JSON strings in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I had passed the json string through ajax in jquery like this. My JSON file has check boxes and list values.

```
 var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(result);
```

**here 'jsonstr' is the selected form elements.**

```
    function runAjax(jsonstr)
    { 
              type:"POST",
              url: "ajax.php",
              data: 'json=' +jsonstr,
              dataType: 'json',
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',

              success: function(){
                  alert('Test results submitted!');

              },

    };
    return false;
```

*In php I am trying to recieve the JSON stringlike this, but it was giving the output like "null".*

```
$data= $_POST['json'];
  //decode Json string to PHP object
  $phpobj = json_decode($data,true);
       print_r($data);
       $phpobj = json_encode($data,true);
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing and and what should be in decoding part? Can anyone help?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Can you show me your JSON string ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send it as json string, please give like this

```
data: {json:jsonstr}
```

so it should be

```
$.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'sample2.php',
                data: {json:jsonstr},
                success : function(data){
                    alert(data);
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

It should work for you.

Actually there is no need to convert the object to json. You can directly give it in `$.ajax` .

```
 var data = {name:"Jack", age:12, place:"CA", marks:70};

 $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        data: data,
        success : function(data){

        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
```

and in php you can read like

```
 $_POST['name']
 $_POST['age']
 $_POST['place']
 $_POST['marks']
```

Comment: _Hi @Diode, Thanks for your respons, Actually I have the form results in json string("jsonstr"). Now I need to pass this jsonstr to php file._

Comment: So you can use the first method

Comment: I think this is going to work only if there is a form containing all needed controls (name, age, place, marks) otherwise, when json is posted to PHP you have to retrieve the data by reading php://input

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of $_POST['json']. It should contain something like {"a":"aaa", "b":"bbbb"}.

Check section "Example #3 common mistakes using json_decode()" here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

In **Javascript** change

<del>`var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(result);`</del>

*and*

<del>`data: 'json=' +jsonstr,`</del>

to a simple

```
data: JSON.stringify({json: result}),
```

.

In **PHP** read data instead of this way

<del>`$data= $_POST['json'];`</del>

in this one

```
$data=json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents('php://input')));
```

Once done that, access your data in this way:

```
$data->{'variable-name'}
```

Answer (score -2):

You're very lucky, I understand this question

```
var jsonObject = eval("(" + jsonFormat + ")");
```

Comment: That's answering the opposite question - how to decode a json string in javascript

Comment: Using eval is evil ... Without further checks this will open up all sorts of security holes in your application